# ggplot2 overwrite one another in Rplots.pdf

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I just discovered the convenience that `Rscript` generates a `Rplots.pdf` by default if the script does some plotting. Only problem is that the different `ggplot`'s overwrite themselves. This does not happen with the default plot functions. How can I avoid that?

Comment: add some commands in your file to output the plots... eg. `p1 <- ggplot( blah blah) + geom_xyz(); pdf( "mynewplot.pdf" ); print( p1 ); dev.off()`, or look into `?ggsave`

Comment: Thanks. I like the fact that it is plotting everything in the same file, thus I am not interested in generating "newplot.pdf" or similar. Well I will get interested as soon as no solution comes up. ;-)

Comment: Read some documentation. You can also do this... `pdf( "myonetruefile.pdf" ); print( plot1 ); print( plot2 ); print( plotn ); ... *some more codez* ... dev.off()`. All your plots will go in the same file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, some recommended reading:

[**`grDevices::pdf()`**](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html)
[**`ggplot2::ggsave()`**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/ggsave.html)
[**`grDevices::dev.*()`**](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/dev.html)
[**`grDevices::Devices`**](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/Devices.html)

Now, a worked example...

```
require( ggplot2 )

#  Make some plots
p1 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, colour=cyl)
p2 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, size=cyl)
p3 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, facets=vs ~ am)

# Open device
pdf( "Test.pdf" )

# Output all plots to currently active device
print( p1 )
print( p2 )
print( p3 )

# Close device
dev.off()
```

Obviously you can choose the point in your code at which you print plots to pdf.

[image]

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. The key command here is `print` of which I was not aware since the qqplot already makes a plot.

Comment: @dmeu Exactly. If you assign the plot to an object, then you can choose to `print` it at any time.

Comment: Yup, and since I did not use print, it was overwriting again and again the same plot in the output pdf.